# Retrieving the value from the function using pointer-to-pointer function argument (provided by library API)

Tags: c, function-pointers, protocol-buffers

I am currently referring to the following example
http://code.google.com/p/nanopb/source/browse/tests/callbacks/decode_callbacks.c#10

I have modified the functions as follows - **because rather than passing value to the function using '**arg' I want to retrieve the value obtained within function using the '**arg'.**

```
bool print_int32(pb_istream_t *stream, const pb_field_t *field, void **arg)
{
    uint64_t value;
    if (!pb_decode_varint(stream, &value))
    return false;
        *arg = (void*) value; // This is 42

    printf("The value = %ld, *arg = %ld, arg = %ld\n", (long)value, (long)*arg, (long)arg); 
    return true;
}
```

`(long)*arg` is now *42* and `(long)arg` holds another value say *'-1234567890'*.
Now, in the main function I changed the code as follows.

```
testmessage.submsg.int32value.funcs.decode = &print_int32;
long int32_dec = (long) &testmessage.submsg.int32value.arg; 
//long int32_dec = *(long*) testmessage.submsg.int32value.arg; //This seems to makes no difference
//long int32_dec = (long) testmessage.submsg.int32value.arg; //This seems to makes no difference
```

`int32_dec` value is same as the one I see in (long) arg (in our example *'-1234567890'*). This is not what I want. Instead I want to get *42* (in our example) Is there something in the code I need to change to obtain *42* (in our example)?

**UPDATE [SOLVED]**
Thanks to *jpa* to confirm my pointers concepts and the syntax (for a moment I thought I was going crazy). The core problem was my obvious foolishness in placing the code snippet incorrectly.

```
//This is wrong
long int32_dec = (long) testmessage.submsg.int32value.arg;
if (!pb_decode(&stream, TestMessage_fields, &testmessage))
    return 1;
```

The reason is it was getting a value that was not updated by decode routine that was different from *42* (in our example.)

```
//This is correct
if (!pb_decode(&stream, TestMessage_fields, &testmessage))
    return 1;
long int32_dec = (long) testmessage.submsg.int32value.arg;
```

Comment: You do realize (long)arg stores the address of arg?

Comment: yes. I do. Well maybe I should print it as %p and arg rather than with (long)arg. I am a little rusty on pointer-to-pointer having used references a lot in C++. In this instance I have to use this library API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have just a single `&` sign too much.
This should work:

```
long int32_dec = (long)testmessage.submsg.int32value.arg;
```

Think of `arg` as a free field that you can use to pass anything, like you are doing. In order to write to it in the callback, you need to use `*arg`, like you are doing. However, outside the callback you can just read it directly, without `&` or `*`.

Comment: I only had & to see value of address. I know this and had this piece of code from your solution already but wasn't working and it knew should work (and now I prove my concepts were not wrong at least for this part) and it wasn't working until I found my stupid mistake today. I had this statement at wrong place. This should be there after actual 'decoding' routine (rather than before it) otherwise it gives me value at that location before decoding which in my case is obviously not '42' (in our example). Damn it!